# Using a variable in Ruby Mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a name stored in the variable `username` and would like to pull users row information when I try

```
result = dbh.query("SELECT * FROM maintab WHERE user = '#{username}'")
```

I get no results. If I put in the username by hand however,  it does return a result. How format my query so that I may use variables?

Comment: Watch out for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I'll be sure to injection attack proof all my queries once I actually get everything working.

Comment: are you sure that `username` variable isn't nil or emty?

Comment: I would recommend using something a little more high level like https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel `DB[:maintab].filter(:user => username)` or `DB['select * from maintab where user = ?', username]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to debug this way:

```
username = "Peter" # any of your real name
result = dbh.query("SELECT * FROM maintab WHERE user = '#{username}'")
```

it should work. Looks like your `username` is `nil` or `blank`

Comment: Crazy: I was putting the username in via gets on screen and output the variable just to make sure it was there and it was. However when I set username like you did above it worked. Turns out there was something extra on the variable and .strip clears it right up. Thanks.

Comment: @Arbiter: You were saying something about getting it working before worrying about data cleansing (i.e. SQL injection)...

Comment: I was stupidly assuming that the gem just had trouble with using variables in queries. That'll teach me...

Answer (score 0):

Open up IRB and try to print what you have.

How does #{} behave with single quotes vs escaped double quotes?

That should answer your question.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I can try the IRB. Im running a script on a remote server. I have it put out the number of rows it finds to see if it found anything. I believe I correctly tried the escaped double quotes and met the same result. Its very possible that I did it incorrectly though