# Pulling an Integer value from SQL database to be used for calculation

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am having trouble just trying to pull data out of my table. I just want to pull the integer value from column `Diff` and add/subtract numbers to it.

Once I am done adding/subtracting, I want to update each row with the new value"

My Table chart for "users" in ruby

[image: My Table chart for "users" in ruby]

This is my code as of now

```
require 'date'
require 'mysql2'
require 'time' 

def test()
  connect = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => "rubydb")
  result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM users where Status='CheckOut'")
  if result.count > 0
    result.each do |row|
    stored_diff = connect.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Diff")
    #stored_diff = stored_diff.to_s  
    puts stored_diff
    end
  end
end

test()
```

I am sure the code in the hashtag  does not work since I am getting like `#Mysql2::Result:0x000000000004863248` etc. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Diff column is set as int already

Comment: That's your resultset, it seems perfectly okay. I wanted to help you but it's not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Ursus
I want to update the existing "Diff" value by adding this to it.

'time_change = ((Time.parse(row['CheckOutDateTime'].to_s) - Time.parse(row['CheckInDateTime'].to_s)) / 60).round'

So row 1's "Diff" will add it's original value to time_change

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) but I'll show you the steps to achieve what you are trying based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5510419/2408342) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836967/2408342).

1. Get User `Id`s and the `Diff` numbers.

   ```
   SELECT `Id`, `Diff` FROM users where `Status`='CheckOut'
   ```
2. Iterate the `result`.

   ```
   result.each do |row|
   ```
3. Assign `Diff` and `Id` into variables.

   ```
   usrId = #{row['Id']};
   diffCal = #{row['Diff']};
   ```
4. Do your calculations to `diffCal` variable.
5. Execute the `UPDATE` query.

   ```
   UPDATE `users` SET `Diff` = '#{diffCal}' WHERE `Id` = '#{usrId}'
   ```

Comment: how would you assign `Diff` into a variable?

Comment: Yeah, sry about that